# C# .NET: How to check if we're running on battery?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

i want to be a good developer citizen, [pay my taxes](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/22/454487.aspx), and disable things if we're running over Remote Desktop, or running on battery.

If we're running over remote desktop (or equivalently in a Terminal server session), we must disable animations and double-buffering. You can check this with:

```
/// <summary>
/// Indicates if we're running in a remote desktop session.
/// If we are, then you MUST disable animations and double buffering i.e. Pay your taxes!
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Boolean IsRemoteSession
{
    //This is just a friendly wrapper around the built-in way
    get
    {
        return System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession;
    }
}
```

Now i need to find out if the user is running on battery power. If they are, i don't want to blow through their battery. i want to do things such as

- disable animations
- disable background spell-checking
- disable background printing
- turn off gradients
- use `graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;`
- use `graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low;`
- use `graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;`
- minimize hard drive access - to avoid spin up
- minimize network access - to save WiFi power

Is there a managed way to see if the machine is **currently** running on battery?

### Bonus Reading

- [How do you convince developers to pay their "taxes"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/22/454487.aspx) *([archive.is](https://archive.fo/iNVg5))*
- [Taxes: Remote Desktop Connection and painting](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/03/508694.aspx) *([archive.is](https://archive.fo/lJx1u))*
- [GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385(VS.85).aspx) *([archive.is](https://archive.fo/Ywbw7))*

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe you can check [SystemInformation.PowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.powerstatus(VS.80).aspx) to see if it's on battery or not.

```
Boolean isRunningOnBattery =
      (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PowerStatus.PowerLineStatus == 
       PowerLineStatus.Offline);
```

Edit:  In addition to the above, there's also a System.Windows.Forms.[PowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstatus(VS.80).aspx) class.  One of its methods is [PowerLineStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstatus.powerlinestatus(VS.80).aspx), which will equal PowerLineStatus.Online if it's on AC Power.

Comment: What would be the equivalent of this for Desktop computers when they are running on DC (e.g. UPS / IPS) ?

Answer (score 9):

R. Bemrose found the managed call. Here's some sample code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Indicates if we're running on battery power.
/// If we are, then disable CPU wasting things like animations, background operations, network, I/O, etc
/// </summary>
public static Boolean IsRunningOnBattery
{
   get
   {
      PowerLineStatus pls = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PowerStatus.PowerLineStatus;

      //Offline means running on battery
      return (pls == PowerLineStatus.Offline);
   }
}
```

Comment: please just return pls == PowerLineStatus.Offline; This hurts my eyes.

Comment: i prefer a helper function, so that people don't have to keep re-learning how to check for power line status. And nobody says that there is only one enumeration value for "on battery". Especially since there is a 3rd value in the enumeration.  i want a single implementation for "are we on battery", and a central implementation that can be fixed when it turns out to be wrong.

Comment: No he is saying that the helper function is fine, but your code has the anti-pattern of if(blah) { return true; } else { return false; } when instead it should just be return(blah);

Comment: @PaulBatum Ahhh, the problem with collapsing into one line is that it returns on the same line.

Comment: @IanBoyd I fail to see the issue? `return PowerLineStatus.Offline == System.Windows.Forms.SystemInfo......` ?

Comment: @Basic How do you inspect the intermediate result of the comparison without either storing it in an intermediate `Boolean` value, or watching the flow control? It's the job of the code to be easy to read, it is the job of the compiler to optimize it. The problem of collapsing the code onto one line (as someone did without my consent) means you cannot inspect the result of the calculation. Because SO is collaborative, i will not edit it back. If it were my code here, i'd hit him in the head with a coffee mug.

Comment: @IanBoyd Personally, I'd put a inspect the result from the calling method (or use QuickWatch) or add the interim variable while I needed it. As you say, the compiler is likely to remove it in a release build anyway, so it makes no difference in a release. That said, it's a matter of style and I take your point. Side note: I detect a little sensitivity to having the answer edited "without consent" (that's accepted behaviour as you must know better than I). It wasn't me, I was just clarifying the point in comments. Feel free to blast at whoever edited it instead.

Comment: @Basic I only mention the edit in case someone sees the answer and is confused by the comments. The answer has been edited from what it originally was. I didn't want to edit it back because some people get touchy when they edit their stuff.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the GetSystemPowerStatus function using P/Invoke. See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa372693.aspx

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace PowerStateExample
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class PowerState
    {
        public ACLineStatus ACLineStatus;
        public BatteryFlag BatteryFlag;
        public Byte BatteryLifePercent;
        public Byte Reserved1;
        public Int32 BatteryLifeTime;
        public Int32 BatteryFullLifeTime;

        // direct instantation not intended, use GetPowerState.
        private PowerState() {}

        public static PowerState GetPowerState()
        {
            PowerState state = new PowerState();
            if (GetSystemPowerStatusRef(state))
                return state;

            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get power state");
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetSystemPowerStatus")]
        private static extern bool GetSystemPowerStatusRef(PowerState sps);
    }

    // Note: Underlying type of byte to match Win32 header
    public enum ACLineStatus : byte
    {
        Offline = 0, Online = 1, Unknown = 255
    }

    public enum BatteryFlag : byte
    {
        High = 1, Low = 2, Critical = 4, Charging = 8,
        NoSystemBattery = 128, Unknown = 255
    }

    // Program class with main entry point to display an example.
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PowerState state = PowerState.GetPowerState();
            Console.WriteLine("AC Line: {0}", state.ACLineStatus);
            Console.WriteLine("Battery: {0}", state.BatteryFlag);
            Console.WriteLine("Battery life %: {0}", state.BatteryLifePercent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the sake of information, I have a windows tablet that do not return information using win32_Battery or PowerStatus. But this worked. +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) to query the operating system about the battery status.

You could find more information here:

- http://69.10.233.10/KB/system/Wmi_Processor_infoWrapper.aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/apr07/hey0409.mspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EverythingInWmi03.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Powerlord's answer doesn't seem to work, probably because it was answered in 2008.

Here is a version that worked for me:

```
Boolean x = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PowerLineStatus == System.Windows.PowerLineStatus.Offline);
```

Comment: I had to use I had to use System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PowerStatus

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe it's exposed in managed code, but you can use the Win32 GetSystemPowerStatus via pinvoke to get this info.

As an aside, you may want to consider using the GetCurrentPowerPolicies or similar to  determine the users preferences relating to performance/power management.

Comment: A quick look at the API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372689(VS.85).aspx) didn't show anything related to any user preferences. It returns things like how slow the CPU will go, and if the monitor will be dimmed, and the fans will be turned off, etc.

Comment: Yes - the CPU speed is a user preference that can be controlled via the Power Settings control panel.

Just a suggestion.

Comment: i was expecting things like "Disable animations", "Disable Glass transparency effects", "Disable alert sounds", etc