# way in .NET/C# to easily know if laptop is plugged in?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, battery

I'd like to call an API to know if the laptop is plugged into the wall.  If it is I want to defer some CPU intense processing in order to save battery

I'd also like to be informed when this status changes (meaning when the user plugs the charger back in I'd like to be alerted)

in Win32 I'd probally go this route - [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

is there something like this in .NET/C#?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347862/how-to-detect-when-laptop-power-cable-has-been-disconnected

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241142/c-sharp-net-how-to-check-if-were-running-on-battery

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can check SystemInformation.PowerStatus to see if it's on battery or not.

```
Boolean isRunningOnBattery =
      (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PowerStatus.PowerLineStatus == 
       PowerLineStatus.Offline);
```

Edit: In addition to the above, there's also a System.Windows.Forms.PowerStatus class. One of its methods is PowerLineStatus, which will equal PowerLineStatus.Online if it's on AC Power.